# Derivative Help for Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the derivative for the following function (Do not simplify your answer):$f(x)= ( x^2+3x−5)^7 (5x^3+4x^2−3x+8) $. So far I got $ (2x+3x-5)^7 (15x^2+8x-3x+8)$ What would I do after this step?

Comment: You may want to google 'product rule'. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%5B%28+x%5E2%2B3x-5%29%5E7%285x%5E3%2B4x%5E2-3x%2B8%29%5D

Comment: Note that $(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use the product rule:

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3x−5)^7\cdot(5x^3+4x^2−3x+8)+(x^2+3x−5)^7\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(5x^3+4x^2−3x+8)$

Can you take it from here?

---

**Help**

Please answer these questions first:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3x-5)^7=$

$\frac{d}{dx}(5x^3+4x^2−3x+8)=$

---

**Solution**:

> $f'(x)=7(x^2+3x-5)^6\cdot(2x+3)\cdot(5x^3+4x^2-3x+8)+(x^2+3x-5)^7\cdot(15x^2+8x-3)$

Comment: So far I have: d/dx= (x^2+3x-5)^7 (15x^2+8x-3x+8)+ (5x^3+4x^2-3x+8)(14x+21x-35)^6 Is this the answer?

Comment: No, sorry, I edited my answer a bit to help you :)

Comment: The answer is the line under 'solution'.

Comment: Now I see where I messed up. 1)(2x+3) 2) (15x^2+8x-3)

Comment: $1$) requires both the power rule and the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+3x-5)^7=7\cdot(x^2+3x-5)^6\cdot(2x+3)$.

Comment: You're welcome! Upvote and click the checkbox! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)= ( x^2+3x−5)^7 (5x^3+4x^2−3x+8) =u(x)v(x)$
So using $f'=uv'+u'v$ We get

$f'(x)=7( x^2+3x−5)^6(2x+3)(5x^3+4x^2−3x+8)+( x^2+3x−5)^7(15x^2+8x-3)$